# Select rows in a numpy array where there are no "holes", the holes being 0 (example ...,1,0,1,...)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, select, filter

How can I select rows in a numpy array where there are no "holes", the holes being 0. For example, if I my input is :

```
M = np.array([[0,10,0,20,30],[15,0,0,25,35],[0,40,40,40,0],[50,0,50,0,50]])
```

I would like the output to be :

```
M = np.array([[15,0,0,25,35],[0,40,40,40,0]])
```

the first and last row were not selected because they have the sequence "non-zero integer , 0 , non-zero integer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `convolution` can be used to detect the holes.

First convert every non-zero to `1` and zero to `0`. So in the places like `101`, the `convolution` with a window `[1,1,1]` for the center index will be `1*1 + 1*0 + 1*1` = 2. So if we check for all zero positions, if the value of the convoluted matrix is `2` we can detect hole condition.

```py
import numpy as np

M = np.array([[0,10,0,20,30],[15,0,0,25,35],[0,40,40,40,0],[50,0,50,0,50]])

M_ =  M.astype(bool).astype(int)
convolved = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.convolve(x, [1,1,1], 'same'), 1, M_)
output = M[list(set(range(len(M_))).difference(np.where((convolved == 2) & (M_==0))[0]))]

print(output)
```

```
[[15  0  0 25 35]
 [ 0 40 40 40  0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

To detect a "hole" in a row, define the following function:

```
def hasHole(row):
    wrk = np.vstack([np.roll(row, -1), (row == 0).astype(int), np.roll(row, 1)])[:, 1:-1]
    return np.not_equal(wrk, 0).all(0).any()
```

Then, to find boolean indices of rows with holes, run:

```
idx = np.apply_along_axis(hasHole, axis=1, arr=M)
```

And finally, to get the expected result, run:

```
result = M[~idx]
```

The result is:

```
array([[15,  0,  0, 25, 35],
       [ 0, 40, 40, 40,  0]])
```